# CLI & Markup language

Tags: utilities

I often find myself editing files for my personal use that are plaintext. Either those are notes, annotations in project directories or sometimes the output of programs that I annotate.

However, sometimes I need to make a "nicer" document out of these plain text files in either MS Word or Latex. Now my question is: is there a simple tool that allows me to convert my plain text files into let's say directly a pdf, tex or doc for further editing that takes Wiki-Syntax into account?

I.e. I'm looking for a rapid prototyping tool for documents where I can annotate them in plain text with a syntax that is as simple as possible but then creates more complicated documents out of them for further editing.

Comment: Take a look at Wikipedia's list of [lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language), pay attention to toolchain and file format support, and try out a few.  The StackExchange sites use a subset of Markdown, so if you like it start with that.  I can also recommend rST (a bit heavier) and LaTeX (much heavier).  In the meantime try to come up with a more specific question that isn't so vague or likely to get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert from Markdown or reStructuredText to LaTeX or MS Word format.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is the most popular markup language as far as I can tell. It is widely supported by various websites and webapps. On the other hand, if you are looking specifically for a language that has nice little CLI converter tool available, then **[text2tags](http://txt2tags.org/)** might be a better shot. At least that was the case when I did my research some time ago.

Anyways, definitely have a look at [the wikipedia article jw013 has posted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language).

Answer (score 0):

If you are Emacs user there is  [Muse Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMuse), that provides [markup languagte (wiki style)](http://mwolson.org/static/doc/muse.html#Markup-Rules).

Using Muse you can publish your file to HTML, PDF, DocBook, LaTeX, [and more](http://mwolson.org/static/doc/muse.html#Publishing-Styles).